# Connection error while writing into Cassandra using pyspark

Tags: cassandra, pyspark

I am trying to write data into Cassandra using Pyspark shell,command:

```
dataframe_name.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(table="table_name",keyspace="keyspace_name").save(mode="append")
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
15/09/15 06:37:18 ERROR DAGScheduler: Failed to update accumulators for ResultTask(2, 198)
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorParam.openSocket(PythonRDD.scala:813)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorParam.addInPlace(PythonRDD.scala:828)
at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonAccumulatorParam.addInPlace(PythonRDD.scala:798)
at org.apache.spark.Accumulable.$plus$plus$eq(Accumulators.scala:80)
at org.apache.spark.Accumulators$$anonfun$add$2.apply(Accumulators.scala:342)
at org.apache.spark.Accumulators$$anonfun$add$2.apply(Accumulators.scala:337)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:226)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:39)
at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:98)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
at org.apache.spark.Accumulators$.add(Accumulators.scala:337)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.updateAccumulators(DAGScheduler.scala:945)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskCompletion(DAGScheduler.scala:1014)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1454)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

I have tried executing the same operation using python shell on pyspark machine. It is working fine.

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
cluster= Cluster(['ip_of_cassandra_machine'])
session = cluster.connect('keyspace_name');
a = session.prepare(""" insert into table_name(t1,t2) values('value1', 'value2') """)
session.execute(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a networking issue from within Spark. Without the exact versions of Spark and the Spark Cassandra Connector it would be hard to diagnose. My guess is that the driver is incorrectly setup for communication with the executors. Are you sure that your driver application is reachable by your executors and vice-versa?

You can always test setting --master local to see if the problem exists when networking is out of the picture.